# No Toasts in Unit test project?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, toast

I am writing some unit tests for a windows store app and I have an interesting scenario concerning my toast notifications.  It seems that when my code under test calls the toast, nothing happens (it never shows up) but when the application is running normally everything works fine.

This behaviour, while being exactly what I want (I don't want to see the toasts while unit testing) is still unexpected.  Why is it that the toasts won't show on the screen while I am running my unit tests?

Comment: Could it be that your unit test project doesn't have the same permissions (that to run the toasts) than in your main project?

Comment: Good question.  I will find out.  I always forget that I have to activate those / expect some kind of output or failure if they aren't enabled.

Comment: To be honest I think you SHOULD get some kind of access denied type message rather than just a silent failure, but I suppose it could be swallowed by the code or unit test.

Comment: The silent failure thing kills me.  I know it is supposed to make things "easier", but in my experience it leads to a bunch of tail chasing while you try to find the problem.  This has been one of my biggest gripes with developing for Win8; no error message, or useless ones. (i.e. "There was an error 0x00800431")

Comment: @dougajmcdonald I have checked, and yes, the toasts are enabled for the unit test project, but still don't show up.  Who knows?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this?

Comment: Nope.  I am still at a loss.  I guess that there is just some thing behind the scenes that removes them, but I don't know what it might be.